# Sums of powers and algebraic integers

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-integers

Suppose that $x_1, \dots, x_n$ are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, and for every integer $N\geq 1$, the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^N$ is an algebraic integer. Does this imply that $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are also algebraic integers? If not, can we get this conclusion with additional assumption that $x_1,\dots, x_n$ and all their Galois conjugates have absolute value $1$?

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4539121/x-1n-cdots-x-ell-n-an-integer-for-all-n-in-mathbbn.

Comment: @Aphelli Thank you!